# multiple mysql joins and proper display ordering

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database setup named "Categories', where categories can be created and have a parent set.
A parent category would be set to "0" under the Parent column, where the id would be used to set its subcategory.

The nested categories can be 4 categories deep:

```
Parent >> Subcategory >> subcategory >> subcategory
```

I have the query setup as so:

```
SELECT *, 
cat_a.id AS A_ID, cat_a.Title AS A_Title, cat_a.Parent AS A_Parent, 
cat_b.id AS B_ID, cat_b.Title AS B_Title, cat_b.Parent AS B_Parent,
cat_c.id AS C_ID, cat_c.Title AS C_Title, cat_c.Parent AS C_Parent, 
cat_d.id AS D_ID, cat_d.Title AS D_Title, cat_d.Parent AS D_Parent
FROM Categories AS cat_a
LEFT JOIN Categories AS cat_b
    ON cat_a.Parent = cat_b.id
LEFT JOIN Categories AS cat_c
    ON cat_b.Parent = cat_c.id
LEFT JOIN Categories AS cat_d
    ON cat_c.Parent = cat_d.id
WHERE cat_a.Username='$UserID'
GROUP BY cat_a.id
```

This displays the information as needed, but the ordering isn't correct.
I'm looking to have the nested displayed so each subcategory with a parent will loop directly under it, like so:

```
Universe
-> Milky Way
--> Planets
---> Earth
---> Mars
--> Moons
---> Titan
---> Europa
-> Andromeda
--> Unknown Planets
---> Planet X
```

etc..

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the data structure correctly, you don't need the `group by`.  Instead, use:

```
order by cat_a.id, cat_b.id, cat_c.id, cat_d.id
```

Comment: That only orders by the id and wont work if items are out of order, or created at a later date. For example, say "moons" was created after everything else, that will sort to the bottom of the array.

Comment: @Andrew . . . "moons" would sort in the group under whichever "A" category it belonged to.  That could be the first group, the last group, or anywhere in-between.